# Bing Maps Ajax API https url?

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

What's the https url for bing maps ajax api? I can't seem to find it anywhere, and am currently using http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3, which is super slow (takes 20-60 seconds to load on each page request!)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I know its a little late for this but what the heck, add https and a parameter s=1 to the end of the map.
Should be like this:

https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3&s=1

Answer (score 3):

There are two endpoints one is for HTTPS and the other for HTTP

**HTTPS:**

```
https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0&s=1
```

**HTTP:**

```
http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0
```